# javac annotation processor : processing dependency classes

Tags: java, annotations, javac, processor

Let's imagine that I have 2 classes in 2 different packages.

Ex:

```
package org.example;
public ClassA {
    @MyAnnotation
    public void xpto() {
      ClassB.staticMethod();
    }
}

package org.another;
public ClassB {

    public void staticMethod() {
           //
    }
    @MyAnnotation     
    public x1() {
    }
}
```

Inside ClassA there is a method with a reference to a ClassB static method.

Now I have a javac process with an annotation processor which will compile every class of /org/example/**

When javac compiles ClassA it will find ClassB as dependence so it will have to compile ClassB too. Does the ClassB will be processed ?

I guess not and I need it to be, do you know how to do it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is quite simple : if ClassB is in the source path, it well be processed. If not, it won't. The fact the ClassA class a method from ClassB doesn't change anything.

The easiest way to check is to print the list of annotated classes given to your processor.